# How can I "concat" rows by same value in a column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to concat rows value in one row in a dataframe, given one column. Then I would like to receive an edited dataframe.

**Input Data :**

```
ID  F_Name  L_Name  Address SSN     Phone
123 Sam     Doe     123     12345   111-111-1111
123 Sam     Doe     123     12345   222-222-2222
123 Sam     Doe     abc345  12345   111-111-1111
123 Sam     Doe     abc345  12345   222-222-2222
456 Naveen  Gupta   456     45678   333-333-3333
456 Manish  Gupta   456     45678   333-333-3333
```

**Expected Output Data :**

```
myschema = {
"ID":"123"
"F_Name":"Sam"
"L_Name":"Doe"
"Addess":"[123, abc345]"
"Phone":"[111-111-1111,222-222-2222]"
"SSN":"12345"
}
{
"ID":"456"
"F_Name":"[Naveen, Manish]"
"L_Name":"Gupta"
"Addess":"456"
"Phone":"[333-333-333]"
"SSN":"45678"
```

}

**Code Tried :**

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Comment: Please specify an expected output and the actual output you are getting.
The 'code' you have tried is loading a dataframe and printing it. It does not relate to your question.

Comment: @samarth I have edit my question. I have just loaded the df and i don't know how to achieve the output in pandas.

Comment: note that if you are willing to have numpy arrays instead of lists, it's more concise to just aggregate `pd.unique` directly: `myschema = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(pd.unique).to_dict(orient='records')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `groupby()`+`agg()`:

```
myschema=(df.groupby('ID',as_index=False)
        .agg(lambda x:list(set(x))[0] if len(set(x))==1 else list(set(x))).to_dict('r'))
```

OR

If order is important then aggregrate  `pd.unique()`:

```
myschema=(df.groupby('ID',as_index=False)
    .agg(lambda x:pd.unique(x)[0] if len(pd.unique(x))==1 else pd.unique(x).tolist())
    .to_dict('r'))
```

so in the above code we are grouping the dataframe on 4 columns i.e `['ID','F_Name','L_Name','SSN']` then aggregrating the result and finding the unique values by aggregrating set and typecasting that set to a list and then converting the aggregrated result to list of  dictionary and then selecting the value at 0th postion

output of `myschema`:

```
[{'ID': 123,
  'F_Name': 'Sam',
  'L_Name': 'Doe',
  'Address': ['abc345', '123'],
  'SSN': 12345,
  'Phone': ['222-222-2222', '111-111-1111']},
 {'ID': 456,
  'F_Name': ['Naveen', 'Manish'],
  'L_Name': 'Gupta',
  'Address': '456',
  'SSN': 45678,
  'Phone': '333-333-3333'}]
```

Comment: code is working fine. Can you give some details about code that will be helpful.

Comment: I was checking code for new id as well but it is not working for that. I have edited my input data. Do you have any suggestion onthat.

Comment: @NaveenGupta added details..kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Thanku so much. Actually I need to grouping on Id column only. I have updated my input and output dataset. let me know if you have something to say on that.

Comment: you can change the grouping to only have `ID` and remove the `[0]` at the end: `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).to_dict('records')`

Comment: @tdy It is giving expected output. Thanku. BTW we have removed [0].

Comment: @NaveenGupta updated answer.... kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @tdy I have new question. Can you please help me in that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677695/read-csv-file-with-header-and-read-the-schema-for-json-convertion-from-json-fil?noredirect=1#comment121371101_68677695

Comment: @AnuragDabas, I have new issue. Can you please help me to solve.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677695/read-csv-file-with-header-and-read-the-schema-for-json-convertion-from-json-fil?noredirect=1#comment121371101_68677695

Comment: @AnuragDabas can you please post your answer here. They have closed my question

Comment: @NaveenGupta but i don't know how to solve  your condition 'I need to read the schema from .json file and apply that schema to data and generate the .json file'

Comment: @AnuragDabas yes I need to read the schema from .json file and need to mapped the data to that schema.